# Node.js - Multipart: XMLHttpRequest get progress of AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, multipart

I have to update the client on the size of the file that's being uploaded, kind of like how youtube does it: you upload a file and until it's 100% uploaded you get an update on how much of it has been uploaded so far. I know that you can get the size of the file that someone wants to upload, with multipart `req.files.myFile.size` and that will give you the full size of the file. But is there a way to get the current size of the file on the disk? Thankn you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with XHR2's `progress` event as documented [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress). For example:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/upload', true);
xhr.onload = function(e) { ... };

// `progress#uploadProgress` looks something like:
//   <progress id="uploadProgress" min="0" max="100" value="0">0%</progress>
var progressBar = document.querySelector('progress#uploadProgress');
// Listen to the upload progress.
xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
  if (e.lengthComputable) {
    progressBar.value = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
    progressBar.textContent = progressBar.value;
  }
};

var form = new FormData(document.querySelector('form#uploadForm'));
xhr.send(form);
```

This will give you the progress of the entire form however and not for individual files.

Comment: Is there a way to listen to an ajax post with xhr? Because I have to upload it with ajax, when have the progress displayed. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, it is? I'm sorry I've never worked with it and... yeah. But the thing is, when I console.log(req.files) I get an empty object, so... what about that?

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the right form to `new FormData()` or that you're appending the files to an empty `FormData` instance before sending?

Comment: Pretty sure actually! `var form = new FormData($('.videoUploadForm'));` But the videoUploadForm class belongs to the form itself, I also tried getting the input field, but I still got the same result! Any advice?

Comment: You need to pass in the actual html element object and *not* a jquery object, so change that to `var form = new FormData($('.videoUploadForm')[0])`

Comment: Oh ok, and is there a way to implement the success and error functions ajax provides?